# Count python dataclass instances

Tags: python, python-dataclasses

what is the best way to achieve class counter implementation with dataclass

```
class geeks:
    
    # this is used to print the number
    # of instances of a class
    counter = 0
  
    # constructor of geeks class
    def __init__(self,name):

        self.name = name

        # increment
        geeks.counter += 1
```

with dataclass:

```
@dataclass
class geeks:
    name : str
```

Comment: So, in short `counter: ClassVar[int] = 0` in your class body, and `def __post_init__(self): geeks.counter += 1` as a method.